# InputStream empty? openStream the cause?

Tags: java, io, jclouds, rackspace-cloudfiles

So I am using the Java SDK solution to download CloudFiles to a local host: [here](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/quickstart/?lang=java)

I am able to find a test container, list what is in it and access/ write the files. But when I write them they don't have any of the data from the original files. They are just husks (0KB). They aren't big files and I seem to have a problem when I call the method `openStream()` to create an `InputStream`... I call `read()` on it and it immediately gives me back `-1` indicating it has come to the end of the file... no idea why. Here is some code to help explain:

```
ObjectList object = objectApi.list();
    for (int x = 0; x < testContainer.getObjectCount(); x++){
        SwiftObject object2 = object.get(x);

        InputStream inputStream = object2.getPayload().openStream();
        System.out.println(inputStream.read()); <-- giving me -1
        System.out.println(inputStream.available()); <-- giving me 0
        String objectName = object2.getName();
        System.out.println(objectName);
}
```

This is just error checking. Everything seems to work with my TestContainer... it will show me all of the folders/files within and when I create:

`Payload pl = object2.getPayload();`

`System.out.println(pl.getMetaData());`

it shows me that the contentLength matches (well almost matches) the size of the file... so I THINK my SwiftObject is being built fine with `object.get(x)`....

No idea WHY I am returning zero bytes when I call `read()`, though... it seems the .openStream isn't working... any help is greatly appreciated!!

And just in case it is somehow an issue with my other code, here is that:

```
InputStream inputStream = object2.getPayload().openStream();
        String objectName = object2.getName();
        System.out.println(objectName);
        if (objectName.contains(".")){
            File newFile = new File("C:\\Users\\-----\\temp\\" + objectName);
            newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            byte[] aByte = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            IOUtils.write(aByte, outputStream); //also tried IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        }
```

Comment: What is your jclouds version? Have you tried to replicate the failure with a different tool like curl?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so for anyone having this problem, the solution was that when I made the code:

```
ObjectList object = objectApi.list();
for (int x = 0; x <testContainer.getObjectCount(); x++){
SwiftObject object2 = object.get(x);
```

This doesn't get the actual object, just a list of the objects and out of that, you get the name. To solve my problem and to get the object with its name, keep the above code but add:

```
SwiftObject realObject = object.get(Object2.getName())
```

This will give you the ACTUAL object. Proceed from there. Hope this helps others....